# Why is onClick function call only passing one character? (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

I'm trying to invoke a function call when the user clicks on a button and pass a variable, however when I console.log the param it outputs only one letter as response (so if gallery is passed it only returns g). I'm not sure whether the way the function is being invoked needs to change, or the function receiving it.

```
const Button = ({selectedIcon}) => {
    const [selected] = selectedIcon;

   return(
      <div className="buttonBlock">
         <span className="btn">
            <input className="btn-outline" type="button" value="Press Me" onClick={ () => getResponse(selected) }/>
         </span>
      </div>
   );
}
```

```
export default function getResponse(selected){
   console.log (selected);
   if(selected === "gallery"){
       console.log (selected);
       getGallery();
   ...
}
```

Comment: `const [selected] = selectedIcon;` ->  `const selected = selectedIcon;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies here:

```
const [selected] = selectedIcon;
```

if selectedIcon = 'gallery',and [selected] = selectedIcon, then selected = 'g'

```
> selectedIcon = 'gallery'
'gallery'
> [selected] = selectedIcon
'gallery'
> selected
'g'
>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this instruction

```
 const [selected] = selectedIcon;
```

you are de-structuring the string which is treated as an array and therefore only returns the first character to the variable `selected`.

More on [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).